# Audio issues / driver name impact ? / snd-hda-intel or snd_hda_intel

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

Using 14.04, i have intermittent issues with audio (works then stops), tried many tips (and actually reverted from 16.04 to a fresh 14.04) but it's still there...

### Question

When applying the troubleshooting procedure, i noticed that the driver is referenced with different names in different places using dash or underscore : `snd-hda-intel` in sound modules, `snd_hda_intel` in hardware devices.

Why these different names ? could this have an impact ?

Thanks for your help

### Sound module

```
find /lib/modules/`uname -r` | grep snd | grep hda | grep intel

/lib/modules/4.4.0-36-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko
```

### Physical audio hardware

```
lspci -v | grep -A5 -i "audio"

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 204f
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at f7d30000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

### Soundplay cards and devices

```
aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with intermittent audio where the device was listed in `aplay -l` but there was still no sound. Output from `dmesg` showed the real issue:

```
snd_hda_intel: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x01270700
snd_hda_intel: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x01270700
snd_hda_intel: azx_get_response timeout, switching to single_cmd mode: last cmd=0x01270700
```

To fix it by adding this line in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1
```

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto#Playing_with_probe_mask